# does the "set" command works in cisco switches?

Tags: networking, cisco, cisco-ios, spanning-tree, vlan

I was trying to change the default port priority on cisco switch and it came with an error as invalid input detected. can someone excplain the mistake in this code !

```
Switch#
Switch#set ?
<cr>

Switch#set spanning-tree ?
% Unrecognized command
Switch#set spanning-tree portvlanpriority 16
       ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cisco prompt with the "#" means you are using a switch with IOS, but the "set" commands are for the older Cisco switches that use CatOS.  You need to look up the IOS commands to accomplish what you are trying to do.  The commands available for the switch will vary based on the switch model and IOS version.